# Android app can see what kind of app installed on my phone

Tags: applications, privacy

I privacy concern about my android 9 phone, my employer ask me to install app on my personal phone.

1. Can this app see what apps installed on my personal phone.
2. If I allowed to this app camera access could this access to my picture and files in gallery.

Comment: That would depend upon the app.  Some can, some can't.  You would have to check with your employer.

Comment: 1. [Package Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility). 2. Camera and Storage are different permissions.

Comment: On Android 9, without XPrivacyLua app, you cannot prevent an installed app from getting a list of all installed apps.